# I'm not getting the readings of sensors connected to an Arduino MEGA correctly using PLX-DAQ

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, datalogging

I'm trying to send data from four sensors that are connected to my Arduino MEGA to an excel file using [PLX-DAQ](https://www.parallax.com/downloads/plx-daq). So I want to keep taking readings at an interval of 1 second until I wish to stop. So I have two questions. First, this code is not working, I just get three readings but all in one row. And I try resetting the Arduino the first time using the physical button on it, and again I get the next set of three readings AFTER I press the reset button the second time. So there is no real-time updation. For example, I upload the code and I click on connect in PLX_DAQ. I see nothing in the Excel file. I press the reset button, and I get three readings all in one row. I wait for some time, I press reset again and I get another three readings and that's it.

Second, how do I control when to start taking readings or stop taking readings, either using Arduino code or by PLX-DAQ.

```cpp
int sensC=A12;
int sensA=A13;
int sensB=A14;
int sensD=A15;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("CLEARDATA");
  Serial.println("LABEL,A0-Voltage,B0-Voltage,C0-Voltage,D0-Voltage");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(analogRead(sensA));
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(analogRead(sensB));
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(analogRead(sensC));
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(analogRead(sensD));
  delay(1000);
}
```

**********EDIT 1**************

@user85471, ok so I added another line right under void loop(), which is: Serial.print("DATA,");

and I ran it again. Now i see my data being stored, but I have four sensors, but only three are of the right output. 
[image]
A0-Voltage should be somewhere around 330-340, but I'm getting some sort of a time output.

Comment: Could you add a copy/paste of what you're seeing in the Serial monitor or your spreadsheet?

Comment: @user85471, please check EDIT 1, and help. Thanks :)

Comment: The first column must always be a timestamp value by the looks of things.

Comment: Go back to using the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE. Edit your question to show that output. My guess is there is some problem with the way you are capturing the data into Excel.

Comment: (You should edit your question to explain what PLX-DAQ is, and include a link. I had never heard of it and had to Google it.)

Comment: Changing the format of column A to a numeric format should display its true value. It looks like it's being displayed as a time, and since the values are all whole numbers, the time is midnight (00:00:00). If you were to change it to a date format, it would probably show a date around early December 1900.

Comment: I'm guessing that your import software assumes that the first column will be a timestamp, hence the change of this column only.

Comment: @DuncanC, yes your guess is right. I had originally checked the output from the serial monitor, and I was getting 4 values. But there is some error in the transfer from Arduino to Excel using PLX-DAQ. If you know any way to save the output from the serial monitor, that would be a useful lead for me. And yes, I'll add a link to explain what PLX-DAQ is.

Comment: @user85471, but I also tried labelling the first column for time and another four for A,B,C,D. Even then I don't get the expected output.

Comment: @Danush, not labelling, but change the actual displayed format of the cells. Select the column, right-click and choose format- you want to change to a number format instead of a date. I don't have Excel here, so I can't tell you the exact wording.

Comment: @Danush: alternative workaround. Add a fifth dummy column before your data. IE before printing the sensA value, print something random (zero would probably work, something like millis() would give some kind of timestamp) followed by a comma. If the column doesn't do what you want, jump over it and ignore it.